# UWP PlaceHolderText in Textbox not showing at runtime

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a small data entry form (ContentDialog) in UWP XAML.

```
<ContentDialog .....>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox PlaceholderText="Name" Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
    <TextBox PlaceholderText="Notes" Height="62" Margin="0" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
    <ComboBox PlaceholderText="Item Type" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemTypeList}" .../>
  </StackPanel>
```

In the designer the placeholder text shows correctly for all controls, but as soon as the dialog is shown at runtime, the placeholder text is blank for the text boxes, even the ones without focus. The placeholder text is correct for the combo box (and some AutoSuggestBox controls) but all TextBox controls show empty - whether they are bound or not.

I am fairly new to UWP, is there something else that could be affecting this?

More Info:

I found that this also happens on normal pages and usercontrols. Only the TextBox seems to be affected.

Testing a bit more shows that if the pages are displayed directly, eg: changing rootFrame.Navigate in App.xaml.cs to display "HomePage" instead of "MainPage", the placeholders show. However my "MainPage" has a hamburger menu (I am using the Devexpress Hamburger Menu Frame) and it seems once this is loaded, my TextBoxes no longer display the PlaceHolderText at runtime. I'll keep testing and maybe raise this with DevExpress as it seems to be an issue with that control. I'll update this post when I solve this.

Comment: I have tried to create a `ContentDialog` following your code. But I can't reproduce the issues. Can you provide more detail code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have narrowed it down a bit and edited the question.